# How I can Open Android Application Automatically Once The Phone Received notification Without any user interaction

Tags: java, android

i search for How I can Open The Android Application Automatically without User Interaction Once the App received FCM , I know The logic  will put it on Method onMessageReceived , Put i donot know How The app Will Open The Activity Without the user press on Notification , App open AUTOMATICALLY

Comment: If the App on Background  , Can We Make it Open automatically Once Received Notification

Comment: Why do you need to open application? If you want to inform user of something the notification is enough and you if you want to start doing some work like synchronize with server there is better ways than opening application.

Comment: The idea is an application that will be placed in an exhibition so that the user can expect some things through it, and the controller will be the company employee through a website that sends notifications according to which the application creates the application pages

Comment: Some feature for example User will Sign , Scan OCR , if employee send Clouding message for OCR app will open Camera to Scan ,  if send Sing app open activity For user to Digital Signature this is why i want to App open automatically based what Received

Answer (score 0):

in your methods onMessageReceived() write somting like

```
Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(TrackingService.this, RequestView.class);
                            dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(dialogIntent);
```

here is my full code in [github](https://github.com/sideeg/Enzar/blob/master/TrackingService.java) but the start activity  method will be good but take care you have to add the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK as i did in the above code to open activity when the app is close